# Differenciate between two distributions using gibbs sampling

Tags: mixed-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-mixture-distribution, hidden-markov-model, gibbs

This question is relate to the post :
" [Conditional distribution for Gibbs sampling for Gaussian mixture](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375896/conditional-distribution-for-gibbs-sampling-for-gaussian-mixture) " but is a little bit different. My objective is to know why the algorithm (which is the same as in the previous post) does not work in a specific case.

**Here is my concern :**

For $t=1,\dots, n$, let's $r_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma_t^2)$ and $$\sigma_t^2=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\sigma^2 & \text{with probability} & p\\
1 & \text{with probability} & 1-p
\end{array}\right.$$ The sample is $r_t, t=1,\,\dots, n$ and we suppose we know the value of $\sigma$ and our aim is to find the value of $p$ using Gibbs sampling. If the prior of $p$ is $\mathcal{B}eta(1,1)$, using the data augmentation, I introduce a process $z_t$ such that : $$z_t=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
1 =  & \text{if} & \sigma_t^2=\sigma\\
0 & \text{if} & \sigma_t^2=1\,.
\end{array}\right.$$
The procedure I use to sample $p$ is :

1- Starting from a certain value for $p=p^{0}$.

2- I compute the density of each data $r_t$ in the sample for the two possible values of $\sigma_t^2$ : $$\omega_1 = f(r_t\mid z_t=0)\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\omega_{\sigma}=f(r_t\mid z_t=1)$$
3- I compute the probability that $z_t=0$ and $z_t=0$ respectively by $$P[z_t=0\mid r_t,p] = \frac{p\omega_1}{p\omega_1+(1-p)\omega_{\sigma}}\,\, \text{ and } \,\,P[z_t=1\mid r_t,p] = 1-P[\sigma_t^2=1\mid r_t,p]$$
4- Now for each date $t$, I have the probability that $z_t=0$ or $z_t=1$. Then I sample $n_{iter}$ times $z_t$ using those probabilities for $t=1,\,\dots,\,n$. At each iteration $j$ ($j=1,\dots,n_{iter}$), the number of time $z_t=0$ will be call $n_0^{j}$ and the number of time $z_t=1$ is $n_{1}^{j}$. Of course $n_{0}^{j}+n_1^{j} = n$ for all $j$.

5- Finally, I sample the posterior of $p$ using $p^{j}\mid (z_1,\,\dots,\,z_n)\sim \mathcal{B}eta(1+n_{0}^{j},1+n_{1}^{j})$

**Problem :**
This algorithm work fine for $\sigma^2$ far from $1$. But, when $\sigma^2$ is close to $1$, the algorithm doesn't not work.

**My understanding :**
What ever the true value of $p$ is, when $\sigma^2$ is close to $1$, $P[z_t=1\mid r_t, p]\approx p$ and does not depend on the data anymore. And then, the posterior is not a posterior as it does not depend on the data. This explanation seems correct because, as $\sigma^2$ is close to $1$ (let's say $\sigma^2=0.9$ or $\sigma^2=1.1$, it is difficult to say if $r_t=0.5$ come from $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$ or from $\mathcal{N}(0,\,0.9)$. The algorithm can the suppose all the data come from $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$ which lead $p$ to be equal to $0$ or from $\mathcal{N}(0,\,0.9)$ ($p=1$) or even give an equal probability to the two distributions.

**My questions :**

- Is there another algorithm to better the sampling of the posterior of $p$?
- Theoretically, is it link to the sample size of the number of iteration of my algorithm? In other words, do you think that If I raise the sample size $n$ or the number of iteration $n_{iter}$ I will find the better the sampling of the posterior of $p$?
- What will be the difference between $1$ and $\sigma$ such that the posterior of $p$ can be found properly? Using my empirical trials, $\sigma^2=0.1$, it works, but when $\sigma^2=0.9$ or $\sigma^2=0.8$ it doesn't work.

All kind of contribution will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an. I saw this question but I does not exactly answer my question. As you cite Diebolt and Robert (1994), you will see in their example 1 (2.1.1) that, the posterior of $p$ is dirichlet, a generalized  form of a beta.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the well the article but the example 2 (sub-section 3.1.1) in the Data Augmentation section of Diebolt and Robert (1994) said that if the prior of p is a dirichlet, the posterior should be also dirichlet. But, my question rely on the fact that this algorithm is not good when $\sigma$ is close to one (two close distributions).

Comment: Yes. I was surely not rigorous in the way I wrote it. I apologize and reedit the question. It is the algorithm for the data augmentation I used. But, my question still remain. I will be happy if you can help me with that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution does not work as

1. the allocation depends on the choice of $p^0$
2. the Beta posterior utilised in Step 5. concentrates to a fixed point with the number of Monte Carlo simulations $n_\text{iter}$ going to infinity, irrespective of the value of the sample size $n$
3. the actual posterior on $p$ is a weighted sum of Beta distributions involving $2^n$ terms.

A valid solution is to resort to Gibbs sampling via data augmentation, as in our [1990-1994 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2345907.pdf):

[image]

where the allocations $z_t^{(m)}$ (or $\sigma_t^{(m)}$) are simulated at *each* iteration $m$ based on the *current* value of the parameter $p^{(m-1)}$, as in Step 3. of the proposal.

Comment: Certainly, the way I ask the question is not the good one. What I mean is : I did exactly the algorithm as in you paper. But, I question still remain and is relate to the fact that the algorithm does not work fine for $\sigma$ close to $1$. I change the way of asking the question here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541677/conditional-distribution-of-the-weight-of-a-mixture-gaussian-with-data-augmentat . Maybe it will be more clear

Comment: Thanks you for your answers